# Generate an integer bigger than 2,147,483,647 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an API for my C# project in PHP to store users, but my problem is that my u_id (user id) doesn't go above `2,147,483,647`. I get the error "duplicate found..." in SQL because I set it as unique, and all id's becomes `2,147,483,647` because it doesn't go above it. I've tried to force it into appending each number as a string onto a variable but that doesn't seem to work. (there are no errors with the code)

```
<?php

    class f {

        public static function randInt($length = 18) {
            $output = array(rand(1, 9));
            $return = "";

            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $output[] = (string)mt_rand(0, 9);
            }

            for($j = 0; $j < count($output); $j++) {
                $return .= (string)$output[$j];
            }

            return $return;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: wha ... why would you make ID field UNIQUE? Just set to AUTO_INCREMENT and UNSIGNED ?

Comment: I need it to be a random large integer

Comment: What column type are you using to store the data?

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question - are you assigning random IDs to users?

Comment: use column type bigint

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes, they have one ID which is incremented and another id which is random.

Comment: @Rahul Shrivastava Did the trick, awesome! Thank you. Didn't realize I had to set that to bigint :p

Comment: @ChristofferHjärtström curious more than anything - why would a user need a random ID instead of a random access key?

Comment: Because my URL will look like this: users/{id}. If I had incremented and my application would get big, the user with the id 1 would very likely get a lot of attention because of their id. And I know I can just use users/{username} but it's my preference

Comment: @ChristofferHjärtström how is incrementing the id any different from random generation? If anything it would be quicker? If you already have an id, why are you creating another one for the user url? just create it so it would be /user/{key} e.g. /user/kfe09sfk3o

Comment: The user id is the same one as the url. They have one incremented id because I want one, and one random. The random one will be the one that goes in the url

Comment: @ChristofferHjärtström apologies ... but to me that makes no logical sense ...

Comment: It doesn't have to, it's my preference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change column type `INT` to `BIGINT`.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname BIGINT;
```